# What's the easiest way to replace the toolchain-test GCC5 with the stock GCC5?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, gcc

I added the [Toolchain test builds ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-toolchain-r/+archive/ubuntu/test) to my Xenial system, so that I could use GCC 7 for development. At some point, it also updated GCC 5 to `5.4.1-2ubuntu1~16.04`, the latest version available in the PPA. However, this version of GCC 5 does not have the recent patches for Spectre/Meltdown. So the last time I did a kernel update (which *was* compiled with those patches), my DKMS modules got recompiled without the patches, version magics didn't match, and they refused to load, breaking various things.

I want to remove the toolchain GCC 5 (and associated packages) and replace it with the stock GCC 5 (ver. `5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9`, which has the retpoline patches), but ideally I'd like to do this without triggering an uninstall of all my DKMS modules and other things that depend on GCC 5. I also want to keep the toolchain-test PPA, for GCC-7. What's the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up doing:

1. Get the list of packages installed from the toolchain PPA associated with GCC-5:

   ```
   aptitude -F "%p" search "?origin(ubuntu-toolchain-r) ?version(5.4.1) ?installed"
   ```
2. For each of these, download the correct version manually:

   ```
   aptitude download cpp-5=5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9
   ...
   ```
3. Install all the downloaded .debs:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```

   (Now is a good time to `apt check` and make sure you didn't break anything.)
4. Pin these packages so that the PPA versions will never be used, by creating a file in `/etc/apt/preferences.d/` containing

   ```
   Package: gcc-5 cpp-5 g++-5 gcc-5-base gcc-5-base:i386 gcc-5-doc libasan2 libgcc-5-dev libgcj16 libmpx0 libobjc-5-dev libstdc++-5-dev
   Pin: release o=LP-PPA-ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
   Pin-Priority: -1
   ```

   Run `apt-cache policy gcc-5` and check to make sure the old version is preferred.
5. Rebuild all DKMS modules:

   ```
   dkms status      # list DKMS modules
   sudo dkms remove modulename/version -k $(uname -r)
   sudo dkms build modulename/version -k $(uname -r)
   sudo dkms install modulename/version -k $(uname -r)
   ```

   Double-check with `modinfo` that the vermagic of the newly-compiled modules includes "retpoline".
6. `reboot`, and hope everything still works.